# Missing file from package unicode-data

Tags: packages, miktex, vscode

I am trying to use VS code to build latex files but I am getting the following problem when trying to output a simple file containing a nomenclature:

```
LaTeX Error: File 'GraphemeBreakProperty.txt' not found.
```

It seems this file should be in the unicode-data package. When I open MiKTeX Console and look for the unicode-data package, I see that it is already installed and when I click on more information, I look at the files it should contain and I do see the `GraphemeBreakProperty.txt` file.

Now when I go to the location of the package on my computer (`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\unicode-data`) I don't find this file, and I can't even download it from the internet and put it there manually since I don't have admin rights.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: update your tex system, it is /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/unicode-data/GraphemeBreakProperty.txt in current texlive

Comment: If you can't update in admin mode, try if you can install a current unicode-data in the miktex console in user mode. That should take precedence over the admin version.